# Exporting fire animation

Tags: animation, collada, fire

as mentioned in the title I want to export my fire animation as Collada(.dae), but this makes my smoke domain an actual cube. Any idea how to fix this since I dont want any smoke at all?
Thanks in advance
[image: flame screenshot]
[image: imported .dae file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, i don't think that's possible to bake a particle and export it as a collada file. If i'm not mistaken you can export it as .mdd to modo, but exporting it to an external game engine or something like that is not supported

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. If I was to fake the fire by using a fluid simulation, would this be supported?

Comment: @EvilMeatball Yes you can, check out this video https://youtu.be/YTDEdZovHbw it might help you